# What are the parts of speech in this exclamatory sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech, exclamations

I am attempting to help a student with a particular sentence:

- *What an amazingly wise creature God made in the otter!*

The exercise asks him to identify if the sentence is active or passive. That question has been answered (active), but we are attempting to determine the parts of speech and uses in a sentence for the rest of it. Here’s what we believe right now.

“God” is the subject. “Made” is the verb. “An amazingly wise” are adjectives modifying “creature,” which we believe to be the Direct Object. We are unable to determine what “what” is and how it is used in this sentence.

Comment: *What a fool I am!* (and the stylistically inverted *What a fool **am I**!* = *I am [a noteworthy example of] a fool!* By the same token, *What an amazingly wise creature God made in the otter! = God made an amazingly wise creature in the otter!* But I don't think "the naming of the parts" is a useful exercise when considering the structure of exclamatory utterances like this."Parts of speech? What good are they here?"

Comment: The exclamatory form is unfamiliar nowadays, but try this trick -- if you can account for _Wh_-questions, change this into one by _Do_-support, auxiliary inversion, and swapping the bang for a question mark: _What an amazingly wise creature did God make in the otter?_ In this question, every word (except the dummy _do_) has the same sense and grammar that it does in the exclamation.

Comment: @John Lawler: Is it an exclamatory pronoun then?

Comment: @Pkjmm: _What_ is a _Wh_-pronoun. _Exclamatory_ isn't a technical term, but a description meaning 'used during exclaiming'.

Comment: Are we sure this is a full sentence? I think it is a noun phrase that can be simplified down to 'What a wise creature (that God made in the otter)"

Comment: Exclamative “what” is an **adjective** functioning as an external modifier. It always occurs in NPs with a following head, where it questions quality or degree. Don't confuse it with interrogative "what", as in "What was that?", which is a pronoun questioning identity. Btw, "what an amazingly wise creature" is object of "made".

Comment: @BillJ That sounds reasonable, but I fell like the parse is such that 'God made' is a relative clause with the 'that' dropped. So I don't see it is a transformation of 'God made a creature', but instead is 'a creature that God made'. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Pkjmm Regarding your request, expect only to hear the sound of fingernails being pared.

Comment: @Mitch If it were a relative clause, then _What an amazingly wise creature (that) God made in the otter!_ would be a verbless exclamative clause consisting of just the exclamative phrase, an NP.  But I think it's better to analyse _What an amazingly wise creature_ as object of "made".

Answer (score 1):

In the terms of the *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* "what" is here an *intensifying **determiner*** (CGEL, § 2.57, p. 88). It is equivalent to "*such*" (CGEL, § 18.57, p. 1416).

- *What* an amazingly wise creature God made in the otter!
- God made *such* an amazingly wise creature in the otter!

Comment: Nah! It's an adjective.

Comment: How can it be a determiner when there is already the determiner "an"? It actually functions as an external modifier. Note that two adjacent determiners are not permitted in English.

Comment: @BillJ According to my reference, it is a determiner; this, of course, does not mean that it should be a *central determiner*, as "a" (an) and "the" for instance, it is not; it is a type of determiner called "predeterminer. The coexistence is therefore no problem: the three types of determiners are regularly found in combinations where they are adjacent to one another. If you make of "what" an adjective how do you explain the place of that adjective **before** the central determiner "an"?

Comment: @BillJ What quality does that would-be adjective, what, confer to the the noun "creature"?

Comment: A predeterminer is not a determiner but a modifier. The term 'predeterminer' means occurring before the determiner, not a kind of determiner. As I said, it's here an external modifier, where it modifies the NP "an amazingly wise creature"

Comment: It questions quality or degree. It's an adjective.

Comment: @BillJ I could accept that a predeterminer is not a determiner as a possibly relevant point of classification but then what justifies the term "central determiner"? It doesn't add up…

Comment: @BillJ Then, how do you explain this from the Cambridge grammar: (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/what?q=What+as+a+determiner) "what as a determiner"?

Comment: I don't follow you. "An" is a central determiner in the NP _an amazingly wise creature_. The external modifier _what_ then modifies the whole NP.

Comment: Could you give us a page reference, please?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I made an edit so as to add the  sections and pages.

Comment: @LPH It may help to think of "what" as indicating a remarkable degree of the property expressed by "amazingly wise", which itself attributes a remarkable degree of wisdom to "creature". "What" then adds even further to that meaning.

Comment: @BillJ I diverge on that point; if some modifier should bear only on "amazingly wise" we would instead have "how", not a determiner in that case but an adverb: "How amazingly wise  did God make the otter!". Nevertheless, I share your point of view to a certain extent insofar as "amazingly wise" should be modified, because I think that it is sensible to think that "what" bears upon "amazingly wise **creature**" (What a creature!, What an amazingly wise creature!); however that particular point is my own feeling, I have no reference.

Comment: @BillJ The correspondence between the nomenclature in CGEL (predeterminer, central determiner, postdeterminer) and the various elements preceding the head  is explained, at least roughly, in this answer of mine (https://english.stackexchange.com/a/547340/349876), to be corroborated with the tables here (Cambridge grammar) https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-position-and-order, in which all elements (quantifier, article, demonstrative, possessive, number) are calles "determiners".

Comment: No: "how" modifies adjectives, degree determinatives, adverbs, and verbs etc., whereas "what" occurs only as modifier in NP structure. Compare, for example, "What a difficult problem that is!" with "How difficult a problem is that!" Same meaning, but syntactically "what" is modifying the NP "a difficult a problem", whereas "how" is modifying the adjective "difficult". Can you see the difference?

Comment: "[What _a difficult problem_] that is!" vs "[How _difficult_] a problem] is that!"

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I think I've grasped that.

Answer (score 1):

> *What an amazingly wise creature God made in the otter!*

Exclamative "what" is an adjective functioning here as an external modifier. It always occurs in NPs with a following head, where it questions quality or degree.

Don't confuse it with interrogative "what", as in "What was that?", which is a pronoun questioning identity.

"What an amazingly wise creature" is object of "made".